# mysql collation type for multilanguage support

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a website that'll store tutorial videos in several different languages. English will be the primary audience, but I expect french accents to be used in usernames/pwds along with swedish/norwegian accents/characters as well.

The languages for the tutorial videos will also be offered in chinese (both cantonese/mandarin), urdu/hindi, farsi/dari, and arabic. While I'm pretty sure the last few use standard qwerty keyboards for the net, especially to register online with - I do know that european keyboards vary and have several accents and ligatures to them.

I was wondering as far as mysql is concerned in terms of storing usernames and email addresses, which collation type would be best suited to support the most probable entries? I know I probably cannot cover them all, but I'd like to do as much as possible.

I've read that uft8_general_ci is better, but how would it vary from latin_1 swedish_ci if I'm looking to support those scandanavian characters?

EDIT:
the user_id field and email fields will be unique - so fred@home.com would not be the same as fréd@home.com

Comment: I'm far from being a MySQL expert but I think that UTF-8 should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The *collation* is pretty irrelevant here for storing data. It only specifies rules for comparison and sorting. What you need is the right *charset*, which should be `utf8`. If your MySQL version is >= 5.5, you should even use `utf8mb4` or `utf16`, both of which cover the entirety of Unicode (MySQL's `utf8` is a limited subset of real UTF-8, covering only the BMP). A `latin1` charset limits you to the 256 characters defined in it.

If you want to avoid similar entries to be seen as the same thing, use the appropriate `_bin` collation.

Comment: i am working on the same issue.I have set the db charset to utf 8 and collation as utf8_unicode_ci .I have set the default charset of table as utf 8 and on top of that..the particular column that will hold the values in diverse languages is also utf8.I use content type as json for my web services.But still the text breaks.Any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `utf8_general_ci`, and use `utf8_unicode_ci` instead. It has much better support for sorting and comparisons, you can derive down `utf8_unicode_ci` to multiple other collation types - for example `utf8_swedish_ci` to get the correct swedish sorting and comparison.

The con is that it's somewhat slower than `utf8_general_ci`, but IMO you gain so much more.